# How to upload the MySQL database dump from local to Acquia cloud?

Tags: drupal-7, acquia

How to upload the MySQL database dump from local to Acquia cloud?, i can see the https://cloud.acquia.com/app/develop UI is changed and i don't find any database import option, someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your local have drush alias, for example by using 'beetbox' Vagrant VM which provides one by defult - more on that here http://ivan.grynenko.com/how-stop-worrying-and-enjoy-developer-life-vagrant

When you setup alias for your local, just update aliases from acquia

```
drush acquia-update
```

and after that you could sync environments as you wish like so:

```
drush sql-drop @acquia_alias.dev
drush sql-sync @site.local @acquia_alias.dev
```

The example above will drop all tables in the Acquia Dev, and then sync your local DB over to Acquia Dev

Comment: two links that support the answer (and offer variations): [How Acquia Dev Desktop works with Acquia Cloud When you push a local database to Acquia Cloud][1] & [Use Drush to Sync Your Drupal Installations Between Multiple Environments][2] by Brant Wynn, April 6, 2016


  [1]: https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/cloud/details#pushdb
  [2]: https://dev.acquia.com/blog/use-drush-to-sync-your-drupal-installations-between-multiple-environments/06/04/2016/10236